# What control should I use for getting the following rows in ssrs?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I am to design a report which will be having given rows, I have tried with  **Tablex** and **Matrix**, but I am facing issue with grouping.

Is there any other control or any custom control or any way of customizing Table

which I can use to design the following formatted rows in report.

Any link with demo, sample or POC would be great help.

[image]

Comment: This is pretty straight forward.  you may be better off searching for a basic tutorial on SSRS.   Is this a duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236745/rdlc-report-designing-help-required)

Comment: Yes I think, I will ask him to delete that  question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind hard to tell what you're going for from your picture/description, but I'm guessing you may want to use a List object. You can put your group at the list object level, and then add text boxes, tables, images or whatever you need inside the list. You'll get a set of whatever is inside the list for each group, using the data from that group. Take a look at the sample/description here, which looks similar to what you're trying to do: [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/microsoft_in_education/archive/2013/03/09/ssrs-using-a-list-item-to-display-details.aspx)

Comment: Thanks it was for my colleague. It helps a lot